# I'm trying to 'draw' curve of random distribution(Galton board) but it 'avoids' certain positions

Tags: python, random

I want to simulate behavior of the Galton board getting a dictionary with position in key and frequency in value.

```
import random

board = {-5:0, -4:0, -3:0, -2:0, -1:0, 0:0, 1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0}

for i in range(200):
  num = 0
  for x in range(5):
    num+= random.choice([-1,1])
  board[num]+=1  # corrected
```

And then I get something like this:
{-5:7, -4:0, -3:35, -2:0, -1:60, 0:0, 1:58, 2:0, 3:29, 4:0, 5:11}

Also when number of positions from 0 to an end is even, the script gives more positions filled but the second and penult ones always remain epmty.
Why is it so and how can I get proper realization of the idea?

Comment: on the last line replace ```d``` with ```board```, this more or less works

Comment: regarding the zero entries:  if you add 5 items selected from [-1, 1] the result will *always be odd.  The even entries on the board will be empty

Answer (score 0):

If you add up -1 and 1 odd times, you get an odd number. If you do even times, you get an even value, therefore if the range you can choose from is [-1,1], you'll have this void problem.

You can add 0 to the list to solve this issue.

```py
import random

board = {-5:0, -4:0, -3:0, -2:0, -1:0, 0:0, 1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0}

for i in range(200):
  num = 0
  for x in range(5):
    num+= random.choice([-1,0,1])
  board[num]+=1
```

Comment: And also, if it is needed to be without adding 0, it can be fixed such way:
changing [-1,0,1] to [-0.5,0.5] and putting in second loop's range double quantity of (end.index-0)

Comment: Or equivalently, you can also set the bin size to 2, e.g. by setting the bins to [0,2), [2,4), [-2,0), etc